# Как увидеть логи в контейнерах lxd

Tags: linux, виртуализация, контейнеры

Начал работать с контейнерами lxc.
Установил lxd:

```
sudo apt install lxd
```

Не могу понять где смотреть логи. В каталоге /var/log контейнера нет файла логов syslog.
На хосте, где запускаются контейнеры логов контейнеров тоже не нашел.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: Логи смотрятся через `journalctl` на хосте.